# How to generate date in this format (2022-04-29T06:07:28.158Z) in linux

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

Looking for solution to generate date in the below format:

```
2022-04-29T06:07:28.158Z
```

Have to use in bash script.

Comment: Try `date -u +%FT%TZ`

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @pmf It is very close, getting out as below:
2022-04-29T06:39:54Z..
2022-04-29T06:07:28.158Z but 4th part is missing with dot 
.158Z >> this part

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to have the milliseconds included (rounded to three places), so add `%3N` to [pmf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) suggestion from the comments:

```sh
date -u +%FT%T.%3NZ
```

Example output:

```sh
2022-04-29T16:23:39.905Z
```